# How to Display FARPROC memory address on MessageBox

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll

So I'm trying to make a MessageBox pop up with the memory address of a FARPROC so I can see the value. I can't seem to do it though. I've tried some wacky stuff too.

This is my unworking example that I last tried.

```
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR) (WCHAR) myFarproc, "Loader", NULL);
```

It just crashes the program, and

```
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR) myFarproc, "Loader", NULL);
```

displays gibberish. Also of note is that the program calling this dll's code is in C#.

Comment: Cast the address to a `std::size_t`, and convert that `std::size_t` to a string. _Casting_ an address to a char is never going to work.

Comment: Unless you're in a 16-bit program `FARPROC` is just a regular pointer.

Comment: `wsprintf()` or `sprintf()` (or `swprintf()` if you're compiling Unicode) in conjunction with a text buffer and a single added line of code will probably get what you're looking for. An `istringstream` will likely also get you there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast a pointer into a string and expect something legible, especially if you cast a random pointer into a a pointer to a C style string (which is what LPCSTR is).

What you need to do is to convert the numerical value of the pointer into a string using something like `sprintf_s` and display the resulting string.

For example (from memory, didn't compile it):

```
char buffer[9];   // Adjust size if you're on a 64-bit system
sprintf_s(buffer, "%x", (size_t)myFarProc);
```

This is assuming that you can use the C++ version of sprintf_s.

Comment: Why don't use `"%p"` and no need to cast to `size_t`?

Comment: True, that. I'd use `int n = snprintf(buffer, buffer_capacity, "%p", (void *) myFarProc);`. If `n >= sizeof buffer`, realloc buffer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it. Am I doing this correctly?

```
size_t pAddy = (size_t) myFarproc;
stringstream ss;
char buff[10];
ss << itoa(pAddy,buff,16);
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR) ss.str().c_str(), "Address", NULL);
```